# Deployment error in WIndows XP [ERROR: SQL Server Database is not installed or not running]

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, windows-xp, clickonce

I have developed a **POS System** Recently and workin on its deployment.

**Application Specifications:**

- The application is basically a POS system.
- Back end = SQL Server 2008 Express R2.
- Front End = C#
- I also used SMO libraries.
- Deployment Method = Click-once.
- Target Framework = 4.0.
- Development Tool = Visual Studio 2012 RC.
- OS = Windows 7 Home Premium.
- Used some SQL feature packs like Shared management Objects, CLR types. and others.

The prerequisites are selected and i packaged them also.

In brand new windows 7 the installation was fine. and application is running upto date.

In win XP the installation is fine. but when i start the app. it colses with this error.

```
SQL Server database is not installed and or not running.
```

and application quits.

**IMPORTNAT NOTE:**
THE 'WINDOWS XP SP3 PROFESSIONAL'
ON WHICH I AM TESTING IS INSTALLED ON VIRTUAL MACHINE

In the code i am running some SMO library functions in order to install *.sql script for the application's first time use.

SQL Server 2008 R2 is installed with all of its dependencies. and other feature packs. All the prerequisites are installed on XP.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run SQLServer Management Studio on the XP VM and see SQLServer? If you run the SQLServer Configuration Manager on the VM, and click on SQL Server Services, does it show the service is running?

How do you have the connections configured? Do you have named pipes and TCP/IP enabled for the SQLServer Network configuration? What about the SQL Native Client configuration?

Do you have SQLServer Express ticked as a prerequisite in the ClickOnce deployment? What happens if you run setup.exe? Does it recognize that it's installed?

The SQLServer Express that's installed -- is it a named instance, or did you leave it as ".\SQLExpress" ? Id the connection string being used by the ClickOnce application right?